# Why background image isn't well positioned in header with text?

Tags: html, css, image, background, header

I'm making some website and got a problem in CSS with header background image. 
It doesn't scale to the window size, also problem is the text of the header which isn't in image.

I wanted background image to be full width and height to be in scale of image (in this case image is 16:9) and H3 text to be in the middle of background.

[Screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Tk5.png)

Snippet:

```css
* {
  /* outline: 1px dotted salmon; */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  /*line-height: 1.428571429;*/
  color: #333333;
  height:100%;
  /* width: 100%; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#navigacija ul {
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 color: #eceff1;
 top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#navigacija ul li { 
 float:right;
}
#navigacija ul li a {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000000;
 padding: 16px;
 font-size: 14pt;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#header {
 background-image: url(https://qyq2vq.bn1304.livefilestore.com/y4mO6k4nj7Bn1PdZK3MXxnxTfup6pcZ9CV1RVzElVbaZqHXGeIsWHoA8dYIGLtxGDelO5jpjDbW7viwUNjUp1ptfrIa6Gzl2mtV8gCCEqfiycIHxrC1R0nVr73m_KmhQ2pXgEjhsGtlnkGEpo928QsIRfnQSs-aM4CwxiwaEzJ-q262AQ1Cqau9q_7J1oA9OHSG_pQDOfyHhgSAUpcdz-BdCw/20170104_164033.jpg?psid=1);
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 line-height: auto;
 background-position: 100% 100%;

}
#header h3 {
  text-align: center;
 font-size: 16pt;
}
p.traka {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 12pt;
 background-color: #eceff1;
 padding: 10px;
}
#zastomi {
 width: 100%;
 height: 25%;
 background-color: #29434e;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>index.html</title>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/e4a38023a1.js"></script>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <!--<div class="container">-->
   <div id="navigacija">
   <!-- <a href="/"  id="logo" title="ARKomp početna">
       ARKomp
      <img src="http://www.arkomp.tk/test/content/logo.png" />
    </a>-->
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
      <li class="klmeni"><a href="index.html"><span class="navigacija_text">Početna</span></a></li>
      <li class="klmeni"><a href="usluge.html"><span class="navigacija_text">Usluge</span></a></li>
      <li class="klmeni"><a href="cenovnik.html"><span class="navigacija_text">Cenovnik</span></a></li>
      <li class="klmeni"><a href="kontakt.html"><span class="navigacija_text">Kontakt</span></a></li>
      <li class="klmeni"><a href="onama.html"><span class="navigacija_text">O nama</span></a></li>
      <li class="drustvene facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/arkomp034"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="navigacija_text">Facebook</span></a></li>
      <li class="drustvene instagram"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/arkomp034"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="navigacija_text">Instagram</span></a></li>
    </ul>
     </div>
   <div id="sadrzaj">
    <div id="header">
     <h1>Početna</h1>
    </div>
    <p class="traka">Zašto mi?</p>
    <div id="zastomi">
     <div class="kvadrati">
      <i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <h3>Kvalitet</h3>
      <p>Naš posao radimo predano i s ljubavlju. Pazimo na svaki detalj ne bi li udovoljili korisniku.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="kvadrati">
      <i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <h3>Mobilnost</h3>
      <p>Trudimo se da vam olakšamo čitav proces nudeći besplatnu uslugu dolaska na kućnu adresu.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="kvadrati">
      <i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <h3>Cena</h3>
      <p>U gradu nećete naći servis sa nižim cenama od naših. Pogledajte cenovnik ispod.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="kvadrati">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <h3>Akcije</h3>
      <p>ARKomp svake nedelje nudi još povoljnije svoje usluge u okviru Top ponude!!!</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <p class="traka">Najnovije:</p>
    <div id="najnovije">
     <div class="boxovi">
      <h4>Top ponuda</h4>
      <p>Tokom ove nedelje na sniženju se nalazi usluga <a href="usluge/instalacija_sistema.html">instalacije sistema</a>. Nova cena je 1000 dinara.</p>
      <div>
       <i class="fa fa-hourglass-half fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <p>14.08.2017 - 20.08.2017</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="boxovi">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet tempus ex. Vivamus scelerisque. </p>
      <div>
       <!--<i class="fa fa-hourglass-half fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <p>14.08.2017 - 20.08.2017</p>-->
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="boxovi">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet tempus ex. Vivamus scelerisque. </p>
      <div>
       <!--<i class="fa fa-hourglass-half fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <p>14.08.2017 - 20.08.2017</p>-->
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> 
    <div id="footer">
     <p>©2017 ARKomp.</p>
     <p>Sajt izrađen od <a href="http://www.arkomp.tk/">ARKomp</a></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  <!--</div>-->
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `background-size: cover;` to make it fill up the element. `background-size: contain;` will keep the image in its ratio, in your case the height is only say 60px and there for it will be 60px height and some width. If that makes sense?

```
#header {
    background-image: url(https://qyq2vq.bn1304.livefilestore.com/y4mO6k4nj7Bn1PdZK3MXxnxTfup6pcZ9CV1RVzElVbaZqHXGeIsWHoA8dYIGLtxGDelO5jpjDbW7viwUNjUp1ptfrIa6Gzl2mtV8gCCEqfiycIHxrC1R0nVr73m_KmhQ2pXgEjhsGtlnkGEpo928QsIRfnQSs-aM4CwxiwaEzJ-q262AQ1Cqau9q_7J1oA9OHSG_pQDOfyHhgSAUpcdz-BdCw/20170104_164033.jpg?psid=1);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: auto;
    background-position: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: It made header full width but it is again in height of h3 text. What to do?

Comment: @MihailoJakovljević You have two options. **1)** You make the header a fixed height and change it in different breakpoints. **2)** you make it 16:9 but that might behave strange in different breakpoints (this can be done two ways).